# Error using dyn.load in ioslides_presentation w/ runtime: shiny

Tags: r, shiny, knitr

A colleague ported thousands of S functions and Fortran subroutines over to R.  The native R functions are contained in 5 .RData files and the Fortran subroutines are contained in 2 .dll files.

To make my documents more portable these files have been uploaded to Blackboard and are loaded into R using

````
---
title: "dyn.load and Shiny"
subtitle: "Why can't we all just get along?"
author: "Jason Freels"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
setInternet2(TRUE)

download.file("http://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/DFORRT.dll",
          paste(c(getwd(),"/DFORRT.dll"), collapse=""),
          method="internal",mode="ab")

dyn.load("DFORRT.dll")

download.file("http://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/SPLIDA.dll",
          paste(c(getwd(),"/SPLIDA.dll"), collapse=""),
          method="internal",mode="ab")

dyn.load("SPLIDA.dll")

a<-url("https://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/echapters.RData"    ); load(a)
b<-url("https://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/RSplida Codes.RData"); load(b)
c<-url("https://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/RSplidaData.RData"  ); load(c)
d<-url("https://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/RSplidaUser.RData"  ); load(d)
e<-url("https://afit.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/users/jfreels/Text data.RData"    ); load(e)
```
````

This code works perfectly for the pdf_document, html_document and ioslides_presentation arguments and when I add `runtime: shiny` I can sucessfully generate a preview of the presentation in the RStudio viewer.  However, when I try to deploy the presentation to shinyapps.io, I get an error: "unable to find function setInternet2"

Previously, I attempted to load the .dll files locally using

```
for (i in 1:2){ dyn.load(list.files(getwd())[grep("dll",strsplit(list.files(getwd()),"\\W+"))][i]) }
```

With this method I can also successfully generate a preview in RStudio, but when I try to deploy the presentation I get a different error saying that the attempt to load the shared library resulted in an "invalid ELF header."

Is there some conflict between shiny (or shinyapps.io) and .dll files?

Thanks in advance,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is not clear in the documentation, but ShinyApps.io uses Linux instances (Ubuntu), so you certainly cannot load .dll files (Windows-only) there. The most natural and portable solution is to make it an R package, put it on Github, use `devtools::install_github()` to install it, then deploy the app to ShinyApps.io. Then the package will be re-installed and compiled on Linux, and you do not need to care whether your Fortran code becomes `.dll` or `.so` or whatever.

If you are really reluctant to make an R package (which is actually fairly easy to do and has enormous benefits), you can certainly call `R CMD SHLIB` to compile your Fortran code, but you should not hard-code the extension to be `.dll`. Depending on your platform, it may be different: use `.Platform$dynlib.ext` instead.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, I thought this was going to be the answer.  I had actually searched for some confirmation that For a non-Linux user I had